# Ошибка flet при запуске файла

Tags: python, flet

Пайтон у меня 3.10 версии, стоит Ubuntu Linux, установил `flet` через `pip install flet`, запустил этот код:

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(ft.Text(value="Hello, world!"))

ft.app(target=main)
```

Выводит эту ошибку:

```
/home/sigma/.flet/bin/flet-0.21.1/flet/flet: error while loading shared libraries: libmpv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sigma/Master/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    ft.app(target=main)
  File "/home/sigma/Master/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_runtime/app.py", line 70, in app
    return asyncio.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/sigma/Master/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_runtime/app.py", line 207, in app_async
    await conn.close()
  File "/home/sigma/Master/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_runtime/flet_socket_server.py", line 191, in close
    if self.__receive_loop_task:
AttributeError: 'FletSocketServer' object has no attribute '_FletSocketServer__receive_loop_task'. Did you mean: '_FletSocketServer__receive_loop'?
```

Comment: Вот тут почитайте, такая же проблема у человека: https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues/2823

Comment: попробуйте flet переустановить